# How can I simplify this selenium / java code to get it working?

Tags: java, if-statement, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can somebody help me with the following Java code used in a selenium webdriver test? I know there are probably better ways to do it but the previous person who worked on it before I took over was learning on the job.

Basically it gets to a page and checks for different elements if it finds them it enters some data into field.

The problem is this code is run against different sites and now there is a problem where on one of the pages the text To date and to_date are both on the page so the test fails because it finds an element endDateParam but no the element to_date.

Can anybody help me get around this? I need it so if it finds the text to_date on the page it will use the to_date param, if it finds the text To date it will use the endDateParam and if it finds the text To date AND to_date it will use which ever param it finds.

I tried adding a try catch which does nothing when caught but it still fails.

```
        if (PWSHelper.verifyTextPresent("To date", driver))
        {
            try {
                 WebElement toDate = driver.findElement(By.name("endDateParam"));
                 toDate.sendKeys(boHelper.nextWeek());
                } catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("endDateParam Not Found");
                    System.out.println();
                }
        }


        if (PWSHelper.verifyTextPresent("to_date", driver))
        {
            try {
             WebElement toDate = driver.findElement(By.name("to_date"));
             toDate.sendKeys(boHelper.nextWeek());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("to_date Not Found");
                System.out.println();
            }
}
```

Comment: Why are you running the same test against different sites? You should be splitting the code out - your problem is much deeper than this, you should have a set of tests for site A, a set of tests for site B. If they have similarities you then start to think about inheritance and different aspects of the Java language that can help provide common code in one place - but you are currently fudging two *totally different* tests together.

Answer (score 0):

How about a function that can be called with your different parameters:

```
private void doSomething(String textToFind, String target)
 if (PWSHelper.verifyTextPresent(textToFind, driver))
        {
            try {
             WebElement toDate = driver.findElement(By.name(target));
             toDate.sendKeys(boHelper.nextWeek());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(textToFind + " Not Found");
                System.out.println();
            }
}
```